# Qt C++ QException issue : debug error

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read objects from an XML file and i need to handle 2 exceptions : when the file cannot be opened and when the file content cannot be loaded. (incorrectly formated) I have written the following function to read the content from the file and 2 clases for the exceptions. The problem is that when i run my application and i am trying to load a file with different format then XML, instead of a frindly message which informs that there is an exception,  i have a debug error : abort() is called.  What i am not doing well?
reading function

```
QList<Vehicle> VehicleHelper::readVehicles(QString fileName){
QList<Vehicle> vehicles;
Vehicle newVehicle;
QFile file(fileName);
QDomDocument document;
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
    throw FileCannotBeOpenException();
}
else{
    if(!document.setContent(&file)){
        throw InvalidXMLContentException();
    }
    file.close();
}

QDomElement root = document.firstChildElement();
QDomNodeList carElements = root.elementsByTagName("Car");
for(int i = 0; i < carElements.size(); i++){

    QDomNode carNode = carElements.at(i);

    QDomElement carElement = carNode.toElement();
    QString carID = carElement.attribute("ID");

    //if the idNumber is null, generate one
    if(carID.isEmpty()){
        QUuid newId = Vehicle::generateID();
        newVehicle.setVehicleId(newId);
    }
    else {
        QUuid id;
        try{
            id = QUuid::QUuid(carID);
        } catch(QException &ex){
            continue;
        }


        newVehicle.setVehicleId(id);
    }
  }
```

the call of the function

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
if(isModified){
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    QString message = "There are unsaved changes! Do you proceed? ";
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Save Changes");
    msgBox.setText(message);
    msgBox.addButton("Don't save",QMessageBox::NoRole);
    msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox::Save);
    msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
    int result = msgBox.exec();
    if(result == QMessageBox::Save){
        VehicleHelper::writeVehicles(cars,filename);
        msgBox.close();
    } else {
        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open file");
        if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
            setFileName(fileName);
            QFile file(fileName);
            try {
                cars = VehicleHelper::readVehicles(fileName);
            } catch(FileCannotBeOpenException &ex) {
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
                msgBox.setWindowTitle("Message!");
                msgBox.setText("Failed to open file");
                msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
                msgBox.exec();
                return;

            } catch(InvalidXMLContentException &ex){
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
                msgBox.setWindowTitle("Message!");
                msgBox.setText("Failed to load data!");
                msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
                msgBox.exec();
                return;
            }

            setTakenNumbersList(cars);
            //set data to the table view
            populate(cars);
       }
    }
 } else {
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open file");
    if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
        setFileName(fileName);
        QFile file(fileName);
        if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
            cars = VehicleHelper::readVehicles(fileName);
            setTakenNumbersList(cars);
            file.close();

            //set data to the table view
            populate(cars);

            ui->actionAdd->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionBy_name->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionBy_registration_date->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionBy_registration_number->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionBy_revision_date->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionBy_type->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionClear_Search->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionDelete->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionEdit->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionSave->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionSave_As->setEnabled(true);
        }
     }

    }
 }
```

main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
try{
    w.show();
} catch(QException &ex){

}
return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptions are thrown from code that runs in the event loop, specifically they will reach the `QCoreApplication::notify()`. This one is indirectly called from `a.exec()`, via an intervening operating system event loop call.

Thus you can't merely wrap `a.exec()` in a try/catch. You must reimplement `QCoreApplication::notify()` as follows:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
   MyApplication(int & c, char ** a) : QApplication(c,a) {}
   virtual bool notify(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev) {
      bool rc = true;
      try {
         rc = QApplication::notify(obj, ev);
      }
      catch (QException &ex) {
         ...
      }
      return rc;
   }
};

int main(...) {
   MyApplication app(...);
   ...
}
```

Another problem with your code is that it screams to use the [State Machine Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/statemachine-api.html). You should have states that represent file being open and closed, and intermediate states when e.g. an "unsaved changes" dialog box is shown. Then you won't have the `ui->actionXYZ->setEnabled(true)` littered around the code. Assuming you have a `fileOpen` state, you'd have

```
fileOpen->assignProperty(ui->actionBy_name, "setEnabled", true);
...
```

Then when the file is open, you emit a signal that is attached to a signal transition in the state machine. The state machine will do the rest - it will enable/disable actions for you, etc.