# aborting the execution with Visual Studio / Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I would like to abort an application execution (done with Qt) with an error message in case there was a problem regarding it.

with abort(); it was not working with me.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Throw an exception that you catch in `main` and report the error then exit from `main`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg
Yes. exactly. So it's about working with Exceptions?

Comment: It's *one* way of doing it, and it will allow you to properly clean up after you.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: [You need to catch the exception in a reimplementation of `QCoreApplication::notify`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19149041/1329652), not in `main`! Think of how the call stack looks when your code is executing. On many platforms, it's not called from main, but from some system API or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to exit the application's event loop with a non-zero result code, and show a message box afterwards. You can either re-spin the event loop manually, or let the messagebox's static method do it for you.

```c++
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>

QString globalMessage;

class Failer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_SLOT void failure() {
        globalMessage = "Houston, we have got a problem.";
        qApp->exit(1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPushButton pb("Fail Me");
    Failer failer;
    failer.connect(&pb, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(failure()));
    pb.show();
    int rc = app.exec();
    if (rc) {
        QMessageBox::critical(NULL, "A problem has occurred...", 
                              globalMessage, QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
    return rc;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Actually, you can just throw `QString` and catch it within `main`, then show message box using that string. Which is simpler.

Comment: @SigTerm: Had you have tried it, you'd know it doesn't work, because on the call stack between the slot where you throw it, and `main`, there's often a bunch of system API functions. [You need to catch the exception in a reimplementation of `QCoreApplication::notify`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19149041/1329652)

Comment: @KubaOber: Actually, I tried it and use regularly. In half of the cases it works by default. In other half you need to reimplement notify. Which is fairly easy.

Comment: To have portable code that always works, you need to reimplement notify and catch exeptions there. You don't need to do anything in `main` unless you want to handle stuff thrown by whatever constructors/methods you invoke in `main` itself. I mean, yeah, `exec()` could possibly throw if it runs out of memory itself, but that's got nothing to do with your code.